# lldb alias for executable

Tags: c++, gdb, llvm, lldb

In my bash_profile file I've defined an alias like so:

```
alias 'myprogram= /path/to/my/program/myprogram'
```

with gdb debugger it used to work simply by tiping gdb myprogram but now with lldb I have to provide all the adress of the executable like so

```
lldb  /path/to/my/program/myprogram
```

I tried to define an alias on lldb like so:

```
command alias myprogram /path/to/my/program/myprogram
```

but it says

```
error: invalid command given to 'alias'. '' does not begin with a valid command.  No alias created.
```

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `target create` (aka `file`) command in lldb.

```
(lldb) tar cr /path/to/my/program
```

You can set up an alias (either on the command line or in your `~/.lldbinit` file):

```
% xcrun lldb
(lldb) command alias cls target create /bin/ls
(lldb) cls
Current executable set to '/bin/ls' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 5099 launched: '/bin/ls' (x86_64)
README.html
README.md
...
```

Comment: I try doing this by command line but It doesn't seem to solve the problem. If the lldbinit file does't exist, do I have to create it?

Comment: Yeah you could do `echo command alias cls target create /bin/ls >> ~/.lldbinit` from Terminal to add the `cls` = `target create /bin/ls` command alias, for instance.